# STM32F4 USART CONFIG

Tags: stm32, uart

The following two statements are true about AVR microcontroller's USART Receiver and Transmitter but im curious about that are these also work on stm32F4 ?

> When the Transmitter is enabled, the normal port operation of the Tx
>   pin is overridden by the USART and given the function as the
>   Transmitter’s serial output.
>
> When the Receiver is enabled, the normal port operation of the Rx
>   pin is overridden by the USART and given the function as the
>   Receiver's serial input.

Comment: Most STM32 processors use something called the Alternate Function configuration to accomplish this; details of how this work vary from chip to chip, for example it is very different between the F1's and many of the others.

Answer (score 0):

No. They are completely different.

Comment: Could you explain more? I am asking this question because i feel i couldn't find my answer from this discussion : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405877/stm32f4-usart-receiver-pin-configuring

Comment: Then ask for clarification on your existing question.  **Do not re-post**.

Comment: The reference manual of the specific STM32F4 device has the information. For code examples how to do it, generate a example project with CubeMX.

Comment: @Justme which page? give more information please.

Comment: @Amin I cannot possibly know which STM32F4 model you have.

Comment: @Justme But it does work correctly when even not to use Alternate Function and just defining the pin as Floating input. I had test that and it works. My question actually is WHY that work correctly ?

Comment: @Justme Mine is STM32F407VG

Comment: Maybe it works because of default AF mappings. That pin might already be selected as the RX pin for the USART you are using. And it's configured as an input, so there is no conflict from the output drivers. You also did not say which USART or UART you are referring to.